# Error al crear un controlador usando n-capas y mvc 5 .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Dominio.dll' or one of its dependencies.The system cannot find the file specified.'

Este es el error que me aparece al crear un controlador en el sitio web.
estoy creando una aplicacion web con n-capas, en este caso tres llamadas: 'Dominio', 'Modelo' y 'CrudWeb' la cual es donde creo los controladores, las otras dos son librerias de clase de .net framework, agregué las dependencias de cada una, al modelo agregué la referencia del dominio, al dominio no le puse ninguna, y al CrudWeb le puse ambas referencias, cabe resaltar que ya lo habia hecho en visual studio 2015 y no me generó problemas con los controladores, el que uso ahora es Visual studio 2017.

Comment: Pero dice que no encuentra el archivo. Esta bien referenciado?

Comment: yo lo referencíe con click derecho en el proyecto CrudWeb-> add-> references y le hice check a ambas.

Comment: y las referencias internas de Dominio.dll estan bien?? no creo que te podamos ayudar mucho, definitivamente algo no se carga.